# How to check heading tags (h1-h6) are in hierarchy order using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

1.how to check h2 tag before h3 tag

2.how to check h3 tag before h4 tag.....like wise
it should check whole html page.

this is my sample code.

```
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <h1>aaaaaaa</h1>
 <img src = "..." />
 <img src = "..." alt="information about image" />
 <input type="image" src="img_submit.gif"  />

 <h2>bbbbbbbbbbbbbb</h2>
 <input type="text" aria-autocomplete="both" role="textbox">
 <input type="text" aria-autocomplete="both">

  <h3>ccccccccc</h3>
   <div role="checkbox" aria-checked="true"></div>
  <div role="checkbox"></div>

  <div role="slider" aria-orientation="vertical"></div>
  <div role="slider" aria-orientation=""></div>
  <a href="www.google.com" aria-expanded="undefined"> venkatesh </a>
  <a href="www.google.com" aria-expanded="false"> venkatesh </a>
   </body>
   </html>
```

above is my html sample html page.

```
public void headingHirarchy(){ 
    try {
         Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "file:///C:/Users/PTGHYD/Desktop/testing.html");

         Elements elements = doc.select("h3");
         for (Element element : elements) {
             Element next = element.previousElementSibling();
             if(next.tagName().startsWith("h2")) {
                 System.out.println("success");
             } else {
                 System.out.println("error");
             }
         }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
```

Comment: Could you show us the HTML you are trying to parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally clear on what you want to do but I *think* you want to walk over a HTML document and validate that the header elements (`h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6`) are in order i.e. that `h6` does not come before `h5` and `h5` does not come before `h4` etc.

**Update** based on your comments it is now clear that not only is ordering important but that there can be no gaps in the sequence i.e. if the HTML document contains a `h4` then that element **must** be preceded by a `h3` which in turn must be preceded by a `h2` etc.

If so, then the following code will do that:

```
// this fails fast i.e. as soon as it find an out-of-order header element, if you are interested in gathering and
// reporting all out-of-order header elements then you'll want to gather the failures in a collection and then
// include the failures in an exception which is thrown **after** you have iterated over all header tag
public void validateHeaderElementOrdering(String html) {
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Elements headerElements = document.select("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6");

    List<String> headerTags = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Element element : headerElements) {
        headerTags.add(element.nodeName());
    }

    // if there is only one entry then it must be h1 because (a) every header must be preceded by its parent and
    // (b) if there is only one header present then this header is not preceded by anything and (c) only h1 has
    // no parent
    if (headerTags.size() == 1) {
        String currentTag = headerTags.get(0);
        long currentTagPosition = Long.valueOf(currentTag.substring(1, 2));

        if (currentTagPosition != 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Header tags are out of order, there's only one header tag and it is not h1!"));
        }
    }

    // now walk the headerTags and for each entry insist that it is preceded by the immediately prior header,
    // based on the ordering h6 -> h5 -> h4 -> h3 -> h2 -> h1
    for (int i = 1; i < headerTags.size(); i++) {
        String previousTag = headerTags.get(i - 1);
        String currentTag = headerTags.get(i);

        long currentTagPosition = Long.valueOf(currentTag.substring(1, 2));
        long previousTagTagPosition = Long.valueOf(previousTag.substring(1, 2));

        if(currentTagPosition != (previousTagTagPosition + 1)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Header tags are out of order: %s came after %s", currentTag, previousTag));
        }
    }
}
```

The following tests cases prove the behaviour of this code:

```
@Test
public void headerElementsWhichAreInOrderAreValid() {
    String html = "<html><body><h1></h1><h2></h2><h3></h3><h4></h4><h5></h5><h6></h6></body></html>";

    validateHeaderElementOrdering(html);
}

@Test
public void headerElementsWhichAreNotInOrderAreInvalid() {
    String html = "<html><body><h1></h1><h3></h3><h2></h2><h4></h4><h5></h5><h6></h6></body></html>";

    try {
        validateHeaderElementOrdering(html);
        Assert.fail("Expected out of order header elements to be deemed invalid!");
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        Assert.assertEquals("Header tags are out of order: h3 came after h1", ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Test
public void headerElementsWhichAreNotCompleteAndInOrderAreInvalid() {
    String html = "<html><body><h2></h2><h4></h4><h5></h5></body></html>";

    try {
        validateHeaderElementOrdering(html);
        Assert.fail("Expected out of order header elements to be deemed invalid!");
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        Assert.assertEquals("Header tags are out of order: h4 came after h2", ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Test
public void willValidateEvenWhenThereIsASingleHeaderElement() {
    String html = "<html><body><h3></h3></body></html>";

    try {
        validateHeaderElementOrdering(html);
        Assert.fail("Expected out of order header elements to be deemed invalid!");
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        Assert.assertEquals("Header tags are out of order, there's only one header tag and it is not h1!", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what the code in my answer does ... finds all `h*` elements and ensures that they are in order. If `h3` appears after `h4` then a RuntimeException is thrown.

Comment: this is condition: 1) Search for h3 tag, if found then check  h2 tag  exist or not above the h3 tag in html page.(same for h4,h5,h6)
If not found then identify this as error.

Comment: 1) Search for h6 tag, if found then check h5 tag exist or not above the h6 tag in html page.

Comment: 2) Search for h5 tag, if found then check h4 tag exist or not above the h5 tag in html page. If not found then identify this as error

Comment: The given code extracts the `h*` elements **in the order in which they appear in the document**. It then validates that they appear in the correct order where "correct" means h6 after h5 after h4 after h3 after h2 after h1. I think that meets your requirement. Why not _try_ the code, see how it works for you.

Comment: first check h6 and before tag should be h5. and check for h5 tag and before tag should be h4. and check for h4 tag before tag should be h3.and check for h3 tag, before tag sould be h2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.In your example if i give h2 first and h4 second and h5 next. in this case it not sowing any error...........it should check for h4 tag and before tag should be h3 tag.

Comment: @VeerabathiniSrinivas I have updated the answer to address the 'uninterrupted sequence' requirement.

Comment: thanks.....almost got it .....but if  only h3 tag is present in document it should check for h2 tag befor h3 tag....if h2 is not not present display error. .i hope now you got my point.

Comment: @VeerabathiniSrinivas I have updated `validateHeaderElementOrdering()` and added a test (`willValidateEvenWhenThereIsASingleHeaderElement`) to verify that this behaviour is covered: "if only h3 tag is present in document it should check for h2 tag befor h3 tag"

Comment: Thank u..@glytching